# Play audio clip over voip, x-lite

Tags: voip

Is there any module or API or any way, in which I can make an audio clip play over VoIP phone like x-lite?

Im looking to make a script or similar so that when I press a button, the participants in the call will hear the audioclip playing.

Best regards

Comment: I don't think X-lite provides any API. It might be done e.g. with PABX or with virtual sound cards and some DAW, but this is rather question for Software Recommendation or Super User.

Comment: One way customize whole flow, get connected with VOIP and using PBX services you can use prerecorded audio / video message.